# How to create a nested array of objects of same type in YAML in Swagger?

Tags: yaml, swagger

I am trying to create a YAML schema in swagger which has a tree-like structure as shown. There should be arrays within arrays within arrays. Using the `$ref` to refer to the same structure, but I am getting blank. It is not generating the complete structure.

```
Asset:
  type: array
  items:
    id:
      type: string
    serial:
      type: number
    ...
    ...
    Asset:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Asset'
```

Result - [image]

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON structure that you're trying to describe?

Comment: **Update -** So, it worked as expected. Although I couldn't see the structure, the classes were generated in the tree format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
   Asset:
     type: array
     items:
       type: object
       properties:
         id:
           type: string
           example:
             "typeExample"
         serial:
           type: number
           example:
              123
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).